# XPath to extract element if one of its children has some text

Tags: html, xpath

Is it possible to craft an XPath query to extract some (html) element if its children has some text, in case, if nesting level is not known ?

For example, html to extract from:

```
    <a href="/dialog/id/7">
        <div class="someclass_1">... random text</div>
        <div class="someclass_2">Text_need_to_find</div>
            <div class="subclass_1">
                Text_need_to_find
           <div class="subclass_2">... random text</div>
                <div class="subclass_3>
                    Text_need_to_find
                </div>
            </div>
    </a>
```

And XPath is required to get `href` attribute if *any* element or subelement has text `Text_need_to_find`.

So basically I want to get `/dialog/id/7` if in any of elements children has text `Text_need_to_find`

Comment: Note that placing `<div>` inside `<a>` is syntactically invalid markup.

Comment: thank you for notice,  this is basically chat box with avatar and text and it was required to make it as clickable link so i made it like this, if You can advice any alternative solution I would be much appreciated ..

Comment: Use `<span>` instead of `<div>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
a[descendant-or-self::*[normalize-space() = 'Text_need_to_find']]/@href
```

if the "Text_need_to_find" is only a part of the content use `contains(., 'Text_need_to_find')`.

Comment: Note that this will also match `<a href="/dialog/id/7"><span>Text_need</span><span>_to_find</span></a>`, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: @hjhughes you are right. To avoid that one can use `normalize-space(text()) = 'Text_need_to_find'`.